# exponential equations with expansion...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, exponential-function, transcendental-equations

> Solve for $x$ in the equation algebraically 
>   $$ 
> 2^x=2x. 
> $$

The solutions are $x =\{1,2\}.$
I have solved it but no one has validated my method. So I thought this website can help.
  I converted to logarithm, ended up with a binomial expansion and then evaluated limits of the series as it tends to zero and infinity. I don't know if it's right. I need help.

Comment: Perhaps showing your work might help you more than just saying what you did

Comment: All we can do at this stage is to give you the solution. But we can't validate your approach, which sounds original.

Comment: This is how I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

$$(2^x-2x)''=2^x\ln^22>0,$$
which says that the graph of $y=2^x-2x$ and a $x$-axes have two common points maximum.

Thus, by your work we got the answer: $\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is transcendental and cannot be solved analytically. Anyway we can isolate the root(s). Indeed, the derivative of $2^x-2x$ is $\log2\cdot2^x-2$ has a single root at $x^*=\log_2\dfrac 2{\log 2}\approx1.5287\cdots$, corresponding to an extremum.

Then $f(x^*)=2^{x^*}-2x^*=\dfrac2{\log2}-2\log_2\dfrac 2{\log 2}\approx-0.1721\cdots$ is a negative number, while $f(-\infty)=f(\infty)=\infty$. As the function is continuous, it has exactly two roots, on either side of $x^*$.

It turns out that if we try the closest integers, $1$ and $2$, we find these roots. But if instead we try $x^*\pm1$ (like could be done in an automated solution), we will find two positive values, showing that the roots lie in
$(x^*-1,x^*)$ and $(x^*,x^*+1)$.

Answer (score -1):

Another method:
$$
\begin{align}
2^x &= 2 x \iff \\
1/2 &= x \, 2^{-x} = x \, e^{-\ln(2) x} \iff \\
-\ln(2)/2 &= -\ln(2) x \, e^{-\ln(2) x} \iff \\
W(-\ln(2)/2) &= -\ln(2) x \iff \\
x &= -\frac{1}{\ln(2)} W\left(- \frac{\ln(2)}{2} \right)
\end{align}
$$
where $W$ is the inverse to $f(x) = x e^x$, the Lambert W "function".

It is defined for negative arguments $x \ge -1/e$ and a double valued relation there.

So we get two solutions.

Comment: 2^x=2x. Taking natural log of both sides, xln2=ln2+lnx. then (x-1)ln2=lnx. Hence ln2=lnx^[1/(x-1)]. We get the binomial 2=x^[1/(x-1)]. If we let n=x-1, then 2=(1+n)^n. We can now expand the series to get 2 = 2 + (1-n)/2 + (1-n)(1-2n)/6 + (1-n)(1-2n)(1-3n)/24 +... Thus factoring out (1-n)/2 from the expansion we get 0= [(1-n)/2][1+ (1-2n)/3 + (1-2n)(1-3n)/12 + ..... Now if (1-n)/2 =0 then n =1 implying that x=2. As for the other, for any term (1-kn)/(k+1)  =0, then n=1/k as k become very large n tends to 0, since n=x-1, x=1. Hence solutions are x={1, 2}. Am I correct